# Are the movies 'The Fantastic World of D.C. Collins' and 'Cloak and Dagger' connected somehow?

Tags: production, cloak-and-dagger, the-fantastic-world-of-dc-collins

In 1984, both [*The Fantastic World of D.C. Collins*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087239/) starring Gary Coleman (TV movie) and [*Cloak and Dagger*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087065/) starring Dabney Coleman (theatrical release) came out.

They have identical plots.

In both, the main character is a child that constantly day-dreams fantastical stories which is the reason no one believes them when they really do get involved in a spy conspiracy, by accidentally coming into possession of secret plans and get chased by bad guys.

IMDb lists the former as being released in February and the latter in August. Is there a story behind these two films being released the same year?

Comment: Aside from the central thesis (young boy accidentally stumbles into spy plot), what other similarities do you see?

Comment: @Richard I added some details above.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it. There are many examples of films being produced that have similar plotlines as other films released in close proximity (so much so that there's an entire page on wikipedia devoted to "[twin films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films)") but aside from a passing similarity between the two, I'm not seeing how they're closely connected. Imaginative boy becomes accidental spy is about as tropey as it gets, especially for an 80s kids film.

Comment: Apropos of nothing, Cloak and Dagger's script (and even the title) was rewritten because the film's makers wanted to get an extensive Atari product placement into the film.

Comment: @Richard it was the fact that the kid in each movie had these elaborate day dreams that made me think (in 1984) that they were so similar. I remember thinking "Hey! they ripped of the Gary coleman movie!" when Cloak and Dagger came out, so I was wondering if there was some kind of industry espionage or anything interesting behind it.

Comment: Good luck proving it. Lots of scripts "do the rounds" and often end up getting ripped off. My gut instinct is that it's pure coincidence. There were a lot of "kid saves the world" movies during that era, largely due to the shift in movie-going demographics.

Comment: Changed the title to something that might be a bit more answerable. Is that OK?